# Why isn't the link color changing back to its previous color on mouse out in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onmouseover

I want to change the color of the link to grey, when the mouse hovers over it. It's working but when I leave the link with my mouse it doesn't change back to its previous color.

I already tried to change it back with the `onMouseOut` event, but this also doesn't work.

```
    handleOver(e){
        e.target.style.color = 'grey';
    }

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <Typography>
                    More information:
                    <Link href='http://localhost:3000' onMouseOver={this.handleOver} color='secondary'> User Manual </Link>
                </Typography>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Add also onMouseOut along with onMouseOver ...and change color yourself. You'll have two event handlers on that Link element. Or just use css hover.

Comment: Use css `a:hover`.

Comment: If you can use CSS, go for it. Much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

in this satiation you need to revert it back to its initial color `onmouseleave` as following:

```
   <Link
            href="http://localhost:3000"
            onMouseLeave={e => (e.target.style.color = "green")}
            onMouseOver={e => (e.target.style.color = "grey")}
            style={{ color: 'green' }}
          >
```

but it is not best practice to achieve this functionally it better to use css

using `a:hover` pseudo-class

Answer (score 0):

`onMouseOver` means **when** the mouse moves over. It doesn't mean **while** the mouse is over.

So when the mouse moves over, you set the colour to grey.

You don't do anything when the mouse moves out.

You could write an `onMouseOut` handler that resets it (`...color = ""`), but this would be better handled with a stylesheet and the `:hover` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

onMouseOut wont work because when you use color like this, it will be fixed to your objective in HTML
There is 2 easy options:

1. Make the onMouseOut change the color of your element to the color you want. 
   `element.style.color = 'your target color';`
2. Make the change of your color with another css property like:
   css:

```
.newColor{
    color: gray;
}
```

javascript for mouse over:

```
handleOver(e){
        Element.classList.add = 'newColor';
    }
```

javascript for mouse out:

```
handleOut(e){
        Element.classList.remove = 'newColor';
    }
```